# Classifying a pandas DataFrame using another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, comparison

I have two tables / pandas DataFrames. `table1` that needs to be classified, i.e. filling the column `class`, based on the data in `a` to `c` ...

```
  a b c class1 class2 class3
0 2 3 4  ???    ???    ???
1 3 5 0  ???    ???    ???
2 9 8 2  ???    ???    ???
```

... and `table2` that provides the classification rules.

```
        a   a   b   b   c   c   
       min max min max min max  
class1  0   9   0   9   0   9  
class2  1   3   4   5   0   1
class3  1   5   3   9   1   3
```

So the goal is to complement the classifications for each row in `table1` by comparing if columns a to c all fall between min and max of `table2`. The result would look like this:

```
  a b c class1 class2 class3
0 2 3 4  True  False  False 
1 3 5 0  True  True   False
2 9 8 2  True  False  False
```

In row 0 that means:

- class1: 0 <= a <= 9 and 0 <= b <= 9 and 0 <= c <= 9 is True
- class2: 1 <= a <= 3 and 4 <= b <= 5 and 0 <= c <= 1 is False
- class3: 1 <= a <= 5 and 3 <= b <= 9 and 1 <= c <= 3 is False

*As an additional difficulty, the number of columns is arbitrary. So the solution should work for different table sizes.*

I could simply loop through both tables and test by line and classification, but that would be very inefficient. Is there a more elegant pandas-like solution?

Comment: Not very clear what you need ...can you show your expected out put

Comment: @Wen True, thank you. I kind of missed to explain the actual check. Please let me know if it is clearer now.

Comment: Also , why class 3 at row 0 is False, since we have a=2 and satisfy 1-5 range

Comment: @Wen Because c=4 and it does not satisfy the 1–3 range in class3. All columns must be True. Added another example in the hope of adding clarity :)

Comment: *"I could simply loop through both tables and test by line and classification"* - please show us the code that does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can using `numpy` broadcast

```
minV=df2.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'min']].values
maxV=df2.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'max']].values
v=((df1.values-minV[:,None])>=0)&((df1.values-maxV[:,None])<=0)

np.all(v,-1).T
Out[251]: 
array([[ True, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False]])
```

Then concat back

```
pd.concat([df1,pd.DataFrame(np.all(v,-1).T,columns=['class1','class2','class3'],index=df1.index)],axis = 1)
Out[254]: 
   a  b  c  class1  class2  class3
0  2  3  4    True   False   False
1  3  5  0    True    True   False
2  9  8  2    True   False   False
```